# Getting JSON data for any site

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

I am trying to build my new App and I need some data for it.

so I was wondering if I can get JSON data (or query link or any source file) of any site for now and for future.

I need to get data from this site: 
https://study.ekb.eg/    -    https://www.ekb.eg/

Note: https://www.ekb.eg/ is the main source data for https://study.ekb.eg/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The site needs to be specifically programmed to return JSON data for you. Regular, normal sites are not like this. They generally just return HTML

So the site owner would need to set up an API for you to consume

Comment: So there is no way to monitor data flow??